# How to log logged in user into file on Sharepoint site?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have .aspx site on Sharepoint 2010 with button that starts download of specific file.
My question is - is it possible to track these downloads, so when user clicks the button it will download the file and also log user's name (or email address or any log-in info) into .txt file?

The actual log into .txt file isn't obviously a problem. The problem is how to get the info from Sharepoint.

I did my research, but I failed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser ?

Comment: Yes, that'll do. Thanks! Very easy.